# Will my cat have long hair or short hair

Tags: breeding

[image][image]
I just adopted this little cuty here and i’m just curious if it’ll have short hair or long hair it seems to me that’s it gonna be long haired Any help i’m thankful i want to know if mine is from the pictures i posted